# Why we need $R$ to be radical at here?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Jacob Lurie used one example for the theorem of Scholism:

Let $R=k[X]$ be the coordinate ring of a variety $X$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Assume $X$ is reduced. Then $MaxSpecR$ is a union of irreducible components $X_{i}$, which are the closures of the minimal primes of $R$. The fields you get by localizing at the minimal primes depend only on the irreducible components, and in fact are the rings of meromorphic functions on $X_{i}$. Indeed we have a map $$k[X]\rightarrow \prod k[X_{i}]\rightarrow \prod k(X_{i})$$

If we do not assume $R$ is radical, this is **not** true.

I am really confused with what he wrote. I have some really elementary questions to ask:

1) Why $R$ is radical matters at here?

2) Why $MaxSpec(R)$ is the union of irreducible components $X_{i}$? If I am not mistaken I think he means the maximum spectrum at here. I understand that points in $X$ corresponds to elements in $MaxSpec(R)$, however why each irreducible component corresponds to a point in $MaxSpec(R)$?

3) How should I understand "..in fact are rings of meromorphic functions on $X_{i}$?" I feel very confused.

Comment: What is Scholism??

Comment: What is a "radical" ring?

Comment: @Georges: From [Akhil Mathew's notes](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/CAnotes.pdf) (21.11), p. 92, it looks like a scholium met a porism. I suspect they indulged in holism and, unexpectedly, there resulted a scholism. We should *proactively* engage in action against such *abus de langage*...

Comment: @YACP: "radical ring" seems to be a typo  for reduced ring.

Comment: @ Martin ${}$  :-)

Comment: The scholism in question is stated with an irrelevant Noetherian hypothesis and I think a more canonical proof that a reduced ring is a subring of a product of fields is to naturally embed it into the product $\prod_{\mathfrak p\in Spec(R)} \kappa( R/\mathfrak p)$ for *all* primes  $\mathfrak p \subset R$ of the residue fields $\kappa( \mathfrak p)=Frac(R/\mathfrak p)$ .

Comment: Sorry for not providing the background. Yes, it is from Matthew's notes.

Comment: @Martin: I emailed Lurie as politely as possible, but did not receive back anything yet. I will moving on with other stuff if he did not write me back.

Comment: I think the right person to mail to would be Akhil (see the introduction of the notes).

Comment: @Martin: So far did not receive anything from Lurie. I am forwarding this to Akhil.